# problema de referencia al request (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();)

Tags: jsf, java-ee, popup

Buen día. tengo una pagina que llama a un pop-up, el cual tiene una tabla con una serie de registros y cada fila tiene un botón de acción (seleccionar).
 Al cargar el pop up la tabla ya viene llena y si hago clic en el botón de acción "seleccionar" de algúno de los registros, se ejecuta la funcionalidad correctamente. Al hacer clic en el botón seleccionar , éste llama al método ***insertarSelect2*** , donse se ejecuta la intrucción : 
**HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();** y una vez ejecutada dicha línea ya,  puedo leer el parámetro del request ***(request.getParameter(“idform:listax”***);

El problema sucede, cuando hago una búsqueda en el pop up (o sea se filtra la tabla) y luego hago clic en el botón "seleccionar".
Al hacer click en “seleccionar”, se llama al método insertarSelect2, pero en éste caso al ejecutar la misma línea donde carga el request, no sé por qué no lee el valor del parámetro. Esto lo ví al hacer un debug de la aplicación.
 Podían orientarme que puedo hacer para corregir esto?
A continuación los fargmentos del código en cuestión:

Método del bean llamado al pulsar sobre el botón "seleccionar"

```
    public void insertarSelect2(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Ingreso a este metodo InsertSelect2...");

            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();

            //String errorReasigNull = session.getAttribute("errorReasigNull").toString();

            //if (errorReasigNull.equals("2")) {
                RetornoDto retorno = new RetornoDto();

                UIParameter idCodCobr = (UIParameter) event.getComponent().findComponent("idCodCobr4");
                UIParameter idTipNegTiend = (UIParameter) event.getComponent().findComponent("idTipNegTiend4");
                UIParameter idcodigoCobradorAnt = (UIParameter) event.getComponent().findComponent("idCodcbrAnt");

                String strCodCobrNuev = idCodCobr.getValue().toString();
                String strTipNeg = idTipNegTiend.getValue().toString();
                String srtCodCobrAnt = idcodigoCobradorAnt.getValue().toString();
                String reg_por = String.valueOf(this.getUsuarioSession().getCodigoUsuario());

                String recup = request.getParameter("idForm:listax");
                //UIParameter recup = (UIParameter) event.getComponent().findComponent("listax");

                //Procesamos recup
                String aRemplazar = recup;
                String remplazado = aRemplazar.replace("[", "");
                remplazado = remplazado.replace("]", "");
                remplazado = remplazado.replace(" ", "");
                remplazado = remplazado + ",.";
                remplazado = "," + remplazado;

                int i = 0, j = 0;
                int pos1, pos2 = 0;
                String var;
                List listaf = new ArrayList();

                while (i < remplazado.length()) {
                    //proceso irrelevante
                }

                // Validamos si se agregó correctamente a la Lista
                for (int e = 0; e < listaf.size(); e++) {
                    System.out.println("LISTA: " + listaf.get(e));
                }

                // Valida y Desactiva e Inserta los ubigeos y Retorna la cantidad que van a pasar
                retorno = gestorcvService.validDesactivaInsertUbigMasiv(listaf,srtCodCobrAnt, strCodCobrNuev, strTipNeg, reg_por);
                GestorcvDto dtoGest1 = (GestorcvDto) retorno.getObjetoRetorno();

                this.mensajeCant = String.valueOf(dtoGest1.getCantPas());
                String cantnopas = String.valueOf(dtoGest1.getCantNopas());

                session.setAttribute("mensaje", mensajeCant);
                session.setAttribute("mensaje2", cantnopas);
                session.setAttribute("codCobr", srtCodCobrAnt);

                AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().returnFromDialog(null, null);

                UIXTable table2 = (UIXTable) this.getTable2();
                //table2.getSelectionState().getKeySet().clear();
            //}

            //session.setAttribute("errorReasigNull", "");
        }
```

Método ejecutado con el botón "buscar" (el cual filtra la tabla de registros)

```
    public String buscarGestoresCVMini() {
            System.out.println("iniciando: buscarGestoresCVMini");
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List lista = new ArrayList();
            RetornoDto retorno = null;

            GestorcvDto gestorcvDto = new GestorcvDto();
            try {
                gestorcvDto.setCodCobrAnt(this.codigoCobrador);
                gestorcvDto.setCodigoCobrador(this.codCobrAux);
                gestorcvDto.setNombres(this.nombresAux.toUpperCase());
                gestorcvDto.setApellidos(this.apellidosAux.toUpperCase());
                gestorcvDto.setCodTienda2("%");

                if (gestorcvDto.getCodigoCobrador().equals("")) {
                    gestorcvDto.setCodigoCobrador("%");
                }

                if (gestorcvDto.getNombres().equals("")) {
                    gestorcvDto.setNombres("%");
                } else {
                    gestorcvDto.setNombres("%" + gestorcvDto.getNombres()+ "%");
                }

                if (gestorcvDto.getApellidos().equals("")) {
                    gestorcvDto.setApellidos("%");
                } else {
                    gestorcvDto.setApellidos("%"+ gestorcvDto.getApellidos() + "%");
                }

                RetornoDto retornoLista = gestorcvService.buscarGestorescvMini(gestorcvDto);
                lista = (List) retornoLista.getObjetoRetorno();

                this.listaGestorescv = lista;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                log.error(new StringBuilder(ex.getMessage()), ex);
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Método que se ejecuta al llamar al pop up y que como se puede ver en el código, llena la "listax"

```
    public void reasignarUbigeos2(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("iniciando: reasignarUbigeos2");
            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();

            UIParameter idCodCobr = (UIParameter) event.getComponent().findComponent("idCodCobr2");
            String strCodCobr = idCodCobr.getValue().toString();

            UIXTable table2 = (UIXTable) this.getTable2();
            Iterator selection = table2.getSelectionState().getKeySet().iterator();

            table2.getSelectionState().getKeySet().clear();
            Boolean flg1 = selection.hasNext();

            if (flg1 == false) {
                session.setAttribute("errorReasigNull", "1");
                FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
                facesContext.addMessage("msjUsuario", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,"No ha seleccionado Ningún Ubigeo", null));

            } else {
                session.setAttribute("errorReasigNull", "2");
                UbigeoDto ubgDto = new UbigeoDto();
                String rowKey = null;
                listax = new ArrayList();

                while (selection.hasNext()) {
                    rowKey = (String) selection.next();
                    System.out.println("rowKey: "+rowKey);
                    //ubgDto = this.listUbigeos.get(Integer.parseInt(rowKey));
                    ubgDto=(UbigeoDto) table2.getRowData(Integer.parseInt(rowKey));
                    this.listax.add(ubgDto.getCodigoUbigeo());
                }

                for(int i=0; i<listax.size();i++){
                    System.out.println("listax: "+listax.get(i));
                }

                this.codigoCobrador = strCodCobr;
                // this.codUbig=stridUbig;
                // this.tipoNegTienda=strTipNeg;

                this.codCobrAux = "";
                this.nombresAux = "";
                this.apellidosAux = "";
                buscarGestoresCVMini();

                //table2.getSelectionState().getKeySet().clear();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Con este código resolví el caso. Ya no tomando la lista desde la vista

```
  String recup = request.getParameter("idForm:listax")
```

sino desde la propia tabla a través de un atributo referenciado en el bean

```
  UIXTable table2 = (UIXTable) this.getTable2();        
   Iterator selection = table2.getSelectionState().getKeySet().iterator();
```

public void insertarSelect2(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Ingreso a este metodo InsertSelect2...");

```
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    //String errorReasigNull = session.getAttribute("errorReasigNull").toString();

    //if (errorReasigNull.equals("2")) {
        RetornoDto retorno = new RetornoDto();

        /**/
        UIXTable table2 = (UIXTable) this.getTable2();
        Iterator selection = table2.getSelectionState().getKeySet().iterator();

        //table2.getSelectionState().getKeySet().clear();
        Boolean flg1 = selection.hasNext();

        if (flg1 == false) {
            session.setAttribute("errorReasigNull", "1");
            FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            facesContext.addMessage("msjUsuario", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,"No ha seleccionado Ningún Ubigeo", null));

        } else {
            session.setAttribute("errorReasigNull", "2");
            UbigeoDto ubgDto = new UbigeoDto();
            String rowKey = null;
            listax = new ArrayList();

            while (selection.hasNext()) {
                rowKey = (String) selection.next();
                System.out.println("rowKey: "+rowKey);
                //ubgDto = this.listUbigeos.get(Integer.parseInt(rowKey));
                ubgDto=(UbigeoDto) table2.getRowData(Integer.parseInt(rowKey));
                this.listax.add(ubgDto.getCodigoUbigeo());
            }

            for(int i=0; i<listax.size();i++){
                System.out.println("listax: "+listax.get(i));
            }


        }
        /**/

        UIParameter idCodCobr = (UIParameter) event.getComponent().findComponent("idCodCobr4");
        UIParameter idTipNegTiend = (UIParameter) event.getComponent().findComponent("idTipNegTiend4");
        UIParameter idcodigoCobradorAnt = (UIParameter) event.getComponent().findComponent("idCodcbrAnt");

        String strCodCobrNuev = idCodCobr.getValue().toString();
        String strTipNeg = idTipNegTiend.getValue().toString();
        String srtCodCobrAnt = idcodigoCobradorAnt.getValue().toString();
        String reg_por = String.valueOf(this.getUsuarioSession().getCodigoUsuario());

        System.out.println("strCodCobrNuev: "+strCodCobrNuev);
        System.out.println("strTipNeg: "+strTipNeg);
        System.out.println("srtCodCobrAnt: "+srtCodCobrAnt);
        System.out.println("reg_por: "+reg_por);
        List listaAux = this.listax;
        //String recup = request.getParameter("idForm:listax");
        String recup = listaAux.toString();
        //UIParameter recup = (UIParameter) event.getComponent().findComponent("listax");

        //Procesamos recup
        String aRemplazar = recup;
        String remplazado = aRemplazar.replace("[", "");
        remplazado = remplazado.replace("]", "");
        remplazado = remplazado.replace(" ", "");
        remplazado = remplazado + ",.";
        remplazado = "," + remplazado;

        int i = 0, j = 0;
        int pos1, pos2 = 0;
        String var;
        List listaf = new ArrayList();

        while (i < remplazado.length()) {
            if (remplazado.equals(",.")) {
                i = remplazado.length();
                break;
            } else {
                if (remplazado.substring(i, i + 1).equals(",")) {
                    pos1 = i + 1;
                    for (j = pos1 + 1; j < remplazado.length(); j++) {
                        if (remplazado.substring(j, j + 1).equals(",")) {
                            pos2 = j;
                            listaf.add(remplazado.substring(pos1, pos2));
                            remplazado = remplazado.substring(pos2,remplazado.length());
                            i = 0;
                            j = 0;
                            pos1 = 0;
                            pos2 = 0;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }           
        }

        // Validamos si se agregó correctamente a la Lista
        for (int e = 0; e < listaf.size(); e++) {
            System.out.println("LISTA: " + listaf.get(e));
        }

        // Valida y Desactiva e Inserta los ubigeos y Retorna la cantidad que van a pasar
        retorno = gestorcvService.validDesactivaInsertUbigMasiv(listaf,srtCodCobrAnt, strCodCobrNuev, strTipNeg, reg_por);
        GestorcvDto dtoGest1 = (GestorcvDto) retorno.getObjetoRetorno();

        this.mensajeCant = String.valueOf(dtoGest1.getCantPas());
        String cantnopas = String.valueOf(dtoGest1.getCantNopas());

        session.setAttribute("mensaje", mensajeCant);
        session.setAttribute("mensaje2", cantnopas);
        session.setAttribute("codCobr", srtCodCobrAnt);

        AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().returnFromDialog(null, null);

        UIXTable table3 = (UIXTable) this.getTable2();
        //table3.getSelectionState().getKeySet().clear();
    //}

    //session.setAttribute("errorReasigNull", "");
}
```